# Custom Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my HTML page instead of using:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.489021, -0.1164075),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: styles
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
}
```

I'd like to use a Custom Map I've created.

https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zd34x9vOEi3A.kNJZAfpCCD80

But I don't want to embed the map into my page, I want to do the styling on the HTML page. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking if you can take a static snapshot of your map, display that, and style it?  If so then of course the answer is yes, in the easiest case just take a screenshot and use a picture editor to get it as a PNG or JPG.  If you want your MyMap to show, and allow the end-user to manipulate the map (zooming, panning), then you have to embed your map onto the HTML using the embed-code that Google MyMaps provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending on what kind of customizing you want to perform on your page, you can include the [**Google Maps JavaScript API 3**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) in your page. This will allow you various customization from adding custom markers, adding images, to calculating and drawing directions. There are even helpful examples, so I'd say it's a great start to add a custom google map to your html.

Comment: I was hoping to have someone else control the map, so I thought using MyMaps would be the easiest for them. But looks like this would be the easiest for me and gives them the customization they want.